# unable to add functions and json object as values to json object properities in Angular js application

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, angularjs

I have the following json array of object.

```
$scope.headerColumns = [{
    "label": "ABC",
    "order": 1,
    "type": "dropbox"

}, {
    "label": "XYZ",
    "order": 2,
    "group": "GroupB",
    "type": "textbox"
}]
```

Now I need to add few more properties to these json objects to contain the following additional information.

```
{
    headerName: "Businesses",
    field: "business",
    cellStyle: {
        'text-align': 'center'
    },
    headerCellRenderer: function(params) {
        params.$scope.businessItems = _self.businessItems;
        return '<span>Businesses</span></br><dropdown-select values=\'businessItems\'></dropdown-select> '
    }
}
```

So I am iterating my json array and adding the new properties as shown below:

```
angular.forEach($scope.headerColumns, function(eachHeaderColumn) {
    eachHeaderColumn["headerName"] = eachHeaderColumn.label;
    eachHeaderColumn["field"] = "busDesc";
    eachHeaderColumn["id"] = "busNum";     
    $scope.formattedheaderColumns.push(eachHeaderColumn);

});
```

Till here it is fine, now I stuck up, not knowing how to add `cellStyle` and `headerCellRenderer` for each json object in the above angular.forEach loop. Can any one help me please in this?

After formatting my final Json should as shown below :

```
$scope.formattedHeaderColumns = [{
    label: "ABC",
    order: 1,
    type: "dropbox",
    headerName: "ABC", //mapped to label
    field: "busDesc", //if order ==1, then field would be "busDesc"
    cellStyle: {
        'text-align': 'center'
    },
    headerCellRenderer: function(params) { //if  type == dropbox, we have function to return the dropdown
        params.$scope.businessItems = _self.businessItems;
        return '<span>Businesses</span></br><dropdown-select values=\'businessItems\'></dropdown-select> '

    }

}, {
    label: "XYZ",
    order: 2,
    group: "GroupB",
    headerGroup: 'GroupB', //header group should be mapped to group, if group is present
    type: "textbox",
    headerName: "XYZ", //mapped to label
    field: "busEntry", //if order ==2, then field would be "busEntry"
    cellStyle: {
        'text-align': 'center'
    },
    headerCellRenderer: function(params) { //if  type == textbox, we have function to return the input box with type = text
        return '<span>XYZ</span></br><input class="exp-param-header-input"  type="text" value=' + params.value + '> </br> <span> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-download"></span> Apply To All</span>'

    }

}]
```

Comment: That's not [JSON](http://json.org). Those are just arrays (of objects) and objects.

Comment: Exactly the same way.

Comment: As you are manipulating the DOM I suggest you review your code - as this is better suited to a directive in angular as the approach you are using is not best practice.

Comment: Show what output you need in json format?

Comment: amoeba, I have edited my question with the expected output format.

Comment: what I am trying is to make my $scope.headerColumns to go with  columnDefs: columnDefs for $scope.gridOptions in ag-grid (http://www.ag-grid.com/best-angularjs-grid/index.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally adding cellStyle and headerCellRenderer is no different than other properties. What is more problematic is setting proper headerCellRenderer function depending on the data. I would suggest that you first prepare a function to generate proper headerCellRenderer function for proper data:

```
function getHeaderCellRendered(data){
    if(data.type == "dropbox"){
        return function(params) {
            params.$scope.businessItems = _self.businessItems;
            return '<span>Businesses</span></br><dropdown-select values=\'businessItems\'></dropdown-select> ';
        }
    }
    if(data.type == "textbox"){
        return function(params) {
            params.$scope.businessItems = _self.businessItems;
            return return '<span>' + data.headerName + '</span></br><input class="exp-param-header-input"  type="text" value=' + params.value + '> </br> <span> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-download"></span> Apply To All</span>';
        }
    }
}
```

and then use it within forEach:

```
angular.forEach($scope.headerColumns, function(eachHeaderColumn) {
    eachHeaderColumn["headerName"] = eachHeaderColumn.label;
    eachHeaderColumn["field"] = "busDesc";
    eachHeaderColumn["id"] = "busNum";   
    eachHeaderColumn["cellStyle"] = {
        'text-align': 'center'
    };     
    eachHeaderColumn["headerCellRenderer"] = getHeaderCellRendered(data);     
    $scope.formattedheaderColumns.push(eachHeaderColumn);
});
```

Alternatively to use [] operator to add new properties to object you may use javascript object inheritance:

```
angular.forEach($scope.headerColumns, function(eachHeaderColumn) {
    eachHeaderColumn.__proto__ = { 
        headerName: eachHeaderColumn.label,
        field: "busDesc",
        id: "busNum", 
        cellStyle: {
            'text-align': 'center'
        },     
        headerCellRenderer: getHeaderCellRendered(data)
    };     
    $scope.formattedheaderColumns.push(eachHeaderColumn);
});
```